# How to list folders and their contents of a GitHub repository using java?

Tags: github, egit, java

Is there any way to list all GitHub repository's folders and their contents without downloading or cloning it to my local using java API like egit or any API?

Comment: you might want to check github rest api to get started

Comment: Yes, the duplicate I proposed uses Python, but I don't really think the implementation language is that important. It's GitHub's API that matters here.